# Adding VIN field to digital toolkit pull

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Was sent here from JHA cases asking if we can have toolkit pull "VIN" field from 20/20 core for an external card we're creating?

tried to pull the VIN field and didn't see it as an option to pass to a third party provider

Comment: I added the `jackhenry-jxchange` tag to see about getting some help on this topic. You're most likely asking about this from the jXchange perspective, as the Banno Digital Toolkit doesn't support pulling a "VIN" field from CIF 20/20.

Comment: thank you, and no I would rather have it pull from toolkit rather than navigate the JX maze for an external card.  am I thinking about this wrong?  It will pass other PII

Comment: Unfortunately, the Banno Digital Toolkit doesn't offer a "BIN" (or "VIN") field in any of the API endpoints. It sounds like jXchange is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the VIN (vehicle identification) from an account, you will use the AcctInq API. If you look in the Mapping section under the CIF2020 provider (https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/acctinq/providers/cif2020/mapping/), you'll find that VIN# maps to LnAcctInqRec.x_LnAcctInfo.LnAcctInfo.VehicleId.

Comment: no, we want vehicle VIN, this is for automotive loans

Comment: Ok, I will update my answer to reflect obtaining the VIN from CIF2020 using jXchange

Comment: But for real, we’re trying to make this simple for the vendor and have them pull it just using toolkit. Is there no new development allowed there?

Comment: The Toolkit doesn't have a way to pull arbitrary data from the core. As mentioned in another comment, the Toolkit doesn't have any APIs which include a Vehicle Identification Number (VIN).